# Breakup/split array into smaller arrays

Tags: swift

I have an array with a text field being a category
`["id", "cat", "item_name"]`:

`["1", "cat1", "Something"]`
`["2", "cat2", "Something"]`
`["3", "cat1", "Something"]`
`["4", "cat1", "Something"]`
`["6", "cat1", "Something"]`
`["7", "cat2", "Something"]`
`["8", "cat2", "Something"]`
`["9", "cat2", "Something"]`

To be able to use the category in UITableView sections I need to split up the array into smaller arrays - right.

So I need to have:

```
dic["cat1"][array of items with cat1 in field]()
dic["cat2"][array of items with cat2 in field]()
```

How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `reduce` or `map` for that. Instead I'd do something like this

```
var dict: [String: [[String]]] = [:]
arr.forEach() {
    if dict[$0[1]] == nil {
        dict[$0[1]] = []
    }

    dict[$0[1]]?.append($0)
}
```

However I'd recommend you change your code structure and models to use a struct. So instead of a nested array do the following

```
struct Item {
    let id: String
    let category: String
    let name: String
}
```

Then the code becomes much cleaner and simpler to read

```
let arr2 = [
    Item(id: "1", category: "cat1", name: "Something"),
    Item(id: "2", category: "cat2", name: "Something"),
    Item(id: "3", category: "cat1", name: "Something")
]
var dict2: [String: [Item]] = [:]
arr2.forEach() {
    if dict2[$0.category] == nil {
        dict2[$0.category] = []
    }

    dict2[$0.category]?.append($0)
}
```

Comment: I don't follow? In this case you'll have 2 keys each with an array of Items as the value.

Comment: My bad, perhaps I shouldn't comment on my phone anymore :p

Comment: You could use: `dict2[$0.category] = (dict2[$0.category] ?? []) + [$0]` to make it shorter though :)